# Print on multiple pages c#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I would like to print more pages using c# . in the function printDocument1_PrintPage which prints the document i have:

```
 int values = 0;
 foreach (DataRow row in rows.Rows)

            values++;
           if (values > 48)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                values = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                e.HasMorePages = false;
            }
```

The problem is that it keeps printing pages without stop. How can i keep track of how many rows to print on page ?

Comment: Could you redefine your question please?

Comment: @pradeepsimha number of lines..

Comment: So if Values is > 48 it should stop printing or if it is less then 48 it should stop printing?

Comment: @pradeepsimha if it has more than 48 rows to create one more printing page and so on at 96 to add one more page..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 int values = 0;
 foreach (DataRow row in rows.Rows)
```

That cannot work, it starts values at 0 for every page.  So it never stops.  You'll need to move the variable outside of the PrintPage method.  You'll also need to implement BeginPrint so you'll start back at 0.  The foreach() is trouble as well, you don't want to start back at beginning for every page.  So rewrite it similar to this:

```
    private int PrintRow;

    private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
        PrintRow = 0;
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e) {
        for (int lines = 0; lines < 48; ++lines) {
            PrintRow++;
            if (PrintRow >= rows.Rows.Count) return;  // Done printing
            var row = rows.Rows[PrintRow];
            // Print row
            //...
        }
        e.HasMorePages = PrintRow < rows.Rows.Count;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer , what do you mean by fix the foreach()?

Comment: Okay, I've rewritten it after seeing from the comments what "values" and "48" might mean.  I guessed at "rows" being a DataGridView.  Please pick better names in your code.